# Computing the limit of an alternating series,

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am looking at the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}.$$ 
This series converges (conditionally) by the alternating series test.  How can I compute its limit, which is equal to -log(2)?

a) I considered $I_n = \int_{0}^1$ $\frac{x^n}{1+x} dx$ -- and showed that this goes to 0, as n goes to infinity (use dominated convergence theorem).

b) I computed [$I_k$ + $I_{k-1}$] (for k $\ge$ 1), and it equals $\frac{1}{k}$.

I should be using my results from a) and b) to compute the above limit, which is part c) of the question that I am working on.

So, I have $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n[I_n+I_{n-1}].$$

Now I'm stuck.  How should I proceed from here?

I checked, by computing explicitly, that $-I_0$ = -log(2).  But I don't know how to arrive at $-I_0$ from the summation that I'm currently at.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$? Or are you trying to find another way to compute that series?

Comment: I would like to use parts a) and b), if possible?  But I'm open to trying another method to compute its limit.  ln(1+x) I have used a lot in the past.  I will look it up now.  I think it's very close to the series for e^x.  Thanks, @JimmyK4542 for your quick hint.

Comment: How can I compute its limit, which is equal to -log(2)?
Do you realize you answered your own question in your question.

Comment: Look at the sum you obtained, say to $n=N$. You end up with a telescoping sum.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - very nice to hear from you and awesome hint.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Bot, I hadn't actually arrived at -log(2) yet; I just knew I had to end up with that number as my answer :)

Comment: @LebronJames: You are welcome. You were essentially finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have gotten $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(I_{n-1}+I_n)$. (You forgot the summation sign).

Now, look at the partial sums:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{N}(-1)^n(I_{n-1}+I_n) = -(I_1+I_2)+(I_2+I_3)-(I_3+I_4)+\cdots+(-1)^N(I_{N-1}+I_{N})$.

A lot of terms cancel. Now, take the limit as $N \to \infty$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Awesome stuff, @JimmyK4542.  I got it now.  Thanks again :)

Comment: he just expanded your series with the taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that uses Abel's theorem (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)).

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n {x ^n \over n}$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n {1 \over n}$ converges, Abel's theorem
gives
 $f(1) = \lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x)$.

The radius of convergence of $f$ is 1, we have
$f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)x^n = {1 \over 1+x}$
and so $f(x) = f(0)+ \int_0^x f'(t) dt = \int_0^x {1 \over 1+t} dt = \ln (1+x)$.

Finally, $f(1) = \lim_{x \uparrow 1} \ln(1+x) = \ln 2$.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much @copper.hat :)